# Error in deploying ear to GlassFish

Tags: glassfish

I am facing to following error when I try to deploy ear to GlassFish server.
Do you have any idea?

```
[#|2014-01-28T19:54:39.068+0900|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
java.lang.RuntimeException: IIOP Protocol Manager initialization failed.  Possible cause is that ORB is not available in this container
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeProtocolManager(BaseContainer.java:821)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.<init>(BaseContainer.java:566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.<init>(StatelessSessionContainer.java:155)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.<init>(StatelessSessionContainer.java:149)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:105)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:257)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:202)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1819.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:184)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getProtocolManager(GlassFishORBHelper.java:219)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeProtocolManager(BaseContainer.java:818)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid iiop-listener orb-listener-1. Lazy-init not supported for SSL iiop-listeners
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.initORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:622)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.getORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:263)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.createORB(GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:152)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid iiop-listener orb-listener-1. Lazy-init not supported for SSL iiop-listeners
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.validateIiopListeners(GlassFishORBManager.java:758)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.initORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:504)
    ... 64 more
```

Comment: This could mean a lot of things. You stack trace doesn't tell us much.

Comment: The stacktrace looks incomplete. Do you use any @Remote interfaces?

Answer (score 2):

The error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid iiop-listener orb-listener-1. Lazy-init not supported for SSL iiop-listeners
```

means a problem with the orb-listener configuration in the `domain.xml`.

I solved the problem in Glassfish 3.1.2 modifying the `domain.xml` file.

On the line

```
   <iiop-listener port="3700" id="orb-listener-1" address="0.0.0.0" lazy-init="true">
          <ssl classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.GlassfishSSLImpl" cert-nickname=""></ssl>
   </iiop-listener>
```

remove the line

```
   <ssl classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.GlassfishSSLImpl" cert-nickname="">
   </ssl>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was more convenient to change the port that generated the conflict.

In the file domain.xml, I modified port 3700 by 3701, in the following line:

**Before:**

**After:**

```
<iiop-listener port = "3701" id = "orb-listener-1" address = "0.0.0.0" lazy-init = "true">
           <ssl classname = "com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.GlassfishSSLImpl" cert-nickname = ""> </ ssl>
    </ iiop-listener>
```